# Need to fix the perl regex to handle multiple cases

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to handle some cases of strings with the regex:
`(.*note(?:'|")?\s*=>\s*)("|')?(.*?)\2(.*)`

Strings:

- note => "note goes here",
- note => 'note goes here',
- note => $note,
- note => "$note",
- note => '$note',
- note => '$note'
- note => $note . $note2  (can go longer, think it as key value of the perl hash)
- #    note => '$note',

There can be multiple spaces in start/end/in between. I need to capture `"` (or `'`), `$note`, `,`or whatever is left after note_section. There can be `#` in beginning if this line is a comment, so, I've included `.*` in beginning. 
Given regex is failing in case 3 as there is `\2` as null.

**Edit:**
Requirement is that I'm reading a file, and replacing the value of note with some tag say `NOTETAG`, and all other things around remain same, including inverted commas and spaces. For that,

- we need to capture the everything from beginning till we start writing the value
- We should capture inverted commas too, so that I can write it back exactly
- We need to capture the value of the note
- We should capture things after the note value as well.

e.g. `note => "kamal"   ,` will become `note => "NOTETAG"   ,` (notice we didnt ate `,` from last)

Answer (score 3):

```
s{
   \b
   note
   \s*
   =>
   \s*
   \K
   (?: (.*)
   |   '[^']*'
   |   "[^"]*"
   )
}{
   defined($1)
   ?  $1 =~ s{\$note\b}{"NOTETAG"}gr
   : '"NOTETAG"'
}exg;
```

Comment: Thanks, modified a bit to handle comment (#) by adding `(.*)` in front. Also in last, moved `,` to a separate capture group :-)

Comment: No, no need for leading `.*`. All that will do is things down a lot (unless you get lucky ans some optimization saves you from that).

Comment: I need that actually. I need to store all those things (including exact number of spaces) and write. This won't be expensive as in my file I have limited number of such lines, in fact it's key value pair in the hash.

Comment: That makes things *worse*. It slows things down when `note` can't be found.

Comment: Still don't need `.*` after the update. /// Updated answer to match new question

Answer (score 1):

Yuo could try `(note\s*=>\s*(?:"|')?)[^'",]+`

Explanation:

`(...)` - capturing group

`note` - match `note` literally

`\s*` - match zero or more of whitespaces

`=>` - match `=>` literally

`(?:..)` - non-capturing group

`"|'` - alternation: match either `'` or `"`

`?` - match preceding pattern zero or one time

`[^'",]+` - negated character class - match one or more chraacters (due to `+` operator) other than `'`, `"`, `,`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/azaa7m/1)

As a replacement use `\1NOTETAG`, where `\1` means first capturing group

Comment: Thanks but, this is just suited if we are doing replacement only and later don't need it. We need to capture the value that we have just replaced with NOTETAG,  Also, this regex breaks if we have value like `note => "9 'o clock",`